# Compilation error with webpack-encore-bundle in Symfony

Tags: symfony5, webpack-encore

I've a project in Symfony 5.3 where I manage JS with the webpack-encore-bundle.
I've been able to compile the JS files in the DEV environment, but I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy in PROD by running *encore production*:

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
    at Function.getCompilationHooks (C:\www\dev\SugaSymfony\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:207:10)
    at C:\www\dev\SugaSymfony\node_modules\@symfony\webpack-encore\lib\webpack-manifest-plugin\index.js:56:24
    at _next37 (eval at create (C:\www\DEV\SugaSymfony\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:97:1)
    at _next15 (eval at create (C:\www\DEV\SugaSymfony\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:189:1)
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\www\DEV\SugaSymfony\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:255:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (C:\www\DEV\SugaSymfony\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (C:\www\DEV\SugaSymfony\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1109:26)
    at C:\www\DEV\SugaSymfony\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1153:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\www\DEV\SugaSymfony\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:22:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\www\DEV\SugaSymfony\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

This error happens in a Windows 2012 Server with PHP 7.4 and Apache while the DEV environment is Windows 10, PHP 7.4 and the Symfony build-in server.

Here is my *package.json* file:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^2.0.0",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.0.0",
        "core-js": "^3.0.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
        "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.1",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0",
        "file-loader": "6.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.13.0"
    }
}
```

And my *webpack.config.js* file:

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/DEV/SugaSymfony/public/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')


    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    // page specific
    .addEntry('showDocs', './assets/showDocs.js')
    .addEntry('certificadoQualificacao', './assets/certificadoQualificacao.js')
    .addEntry('novaQualificacao', './assets/novaQualificacao.js')
    .addEntry('novaEspecificacao', './assets/novaEspecificacao.js')
    .addEntry('novoSimulador', './assets/novoSimulador.js')
    .addEntry('novaOrganizacao', './assets/novaOrganizacao.js')
    .addEntry('novaSpecAdm', './assets/novaSpecAdm.js')

    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

     .copyFiles({
         from: './assets/img'
     })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    //.enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

and, finally, my *composer.json* file:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "amphp/http-client": "^4.6",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.3",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "it/input-mask-bundle": "^1.3",
        "laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge": "^1.3",
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^2.12",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "pugx/autocompleter-bundle": "^1.7",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/intl": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/ldap": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3",
        "symfony/process": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.12",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.3.*",
        "anac/checks": "^1.0.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.3.*"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://bitbucket.org/********"
        }
    ]
}
```

From what I've searched, it appears the problem might be having two version of *webpack* installed, but I couldn't verify that. I've tried some suggested solutions, like reinstalling Node.js, erasing the *node_modules* directory among others without success.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error with webpack. I solved the problem by adding camelCase letters into the path to the directory in which the command is executed.

Let's take the following case:

I develop an application in the directory :

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\myApp
```

I compile the assets of this application with webpack. The Compilation type error is triggered if I execute the `npm run dev` command in `c:\users\username\desktop\myapp` because webpack can't find the node_modules folder. **To fix the error you just have to run your command into the right directory with also camelCase letters.**

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\myApp> npm run dev
```

Webpack should find the node_modules folder and you won't have any more errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but the error I'm getting is not caused by the 'node_modules' directory not being found, but I tried anyway and the error persisted.